# Adding InventTable fields to InventOnHandItem form

Tags: axapta, x++, ax

I'm trying to add InventTable table fields into InventOnHandItem form, I added InventTable in InventOnHandForm datasource and tested all kind of linktype properties with no results.

I also tried to modify InventSum table by adding InventTable in relations with link on ItemId but I have some weird results:
if I change focus on InventOnHandItem form grid Lines, correct InventTable field datas appears on the grid first line

I think I should add some code on form datasource to correct focus,display and refresh problems but I have no ideas about how to proceed.

Does anyone have any ideas to help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I can't use display methods because I need to filter on the InventTable added fields

Comment: After you add the InventTable to the form, do you then add the inventTable fields to the grid? Could you provide some more information about what it is you are trying to do and what it is that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `InventTable` fields being searchable on the grid, you will have to redesign the form completely.

This will involve adding `InventTable`, `InventSum` and `InvenDim` as datasources inner joined (in the specified order) and adding the relevant `InventTable` fields to the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the fields as [display methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) on the `InventSum` table.

To speed things up you could use [caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa596691.aspx).

See also [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Display_method).